# mysql_real_escape_string and strip_slashes problems

Tags: php, mysql

I have `$_POST` in form through PHP into a MYSQL DB that have apostrophes like "O'Hara" and then I get slashes. I know that mysql_real_escape_string puts slashes to prevent things like that but how can I check a DB with a string that has apostrophes in it?

Example:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['full_name']));
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `stadiums` WHERE `stadium_name` LIKE '%$name%' LIMIT 0, 10") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$name = $_POST['full_name'];
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
  $name = stripslashes($name);
}
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `stadiums` 
  WHERE `stadium_name` LIKE '%$name%' LIMIT 0, 10") or die(mysql_error());
```

Use `stripslashes` on input only if [`magic quotes`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) is enabled.